# Orthogonality and linear dependence

Tags: orthogonality

Is it (always) true that for three vectors x, y,z, having x and y orthogonal and y  orthogonal to z means that x and z are linearly dependent?

I have used a simple graphic argument to 'prove' it can be true. But I'd like to know if it is always true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about$R^3$?

Comment: $x=z$?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DavidMitra or $x=-z?$

Comment: Thank you. @Johndoe I'm talking about vectors in R^n. DavidMitra and Johndoe If x=z or -z, the answer would be yes because it would mean that x and z are linearly dependent. What I'd like is a mathematical proof that generalizes the cases you treat in your answers.